# Why does web page behave differently in an iframe?

Tags: iframe

With this html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://darwin-online.org.uk/content/frameset?pageseq=159&itemID=EH88202366&viewtype=text" width="600" height="600"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

it doesn't open showing the requested page 159, which it does (after a slight delay) if you put that same URL in the Chrome browser.
How can I make the iframe go to the requested page?

Comment: Are you trying to display the iframe on an HTTPS site? If so that is the issue, your link is not secure (i.e. HTTP), you cannot display sites without security on sites with SSL. Looking at the site you list for the iframe it doesn't support HTTPS, for whatever reason, so I'm guessing your issue is there.

Comment: @ViaTech I was displaying the iframe on a non HTTPS site, otherwise it wouldn't open the link at all. From the non HTTPS site it does display the introductory material of the link but does not jump to the requested page. But you have a good point, as I intended eventually to use this on an HTTPS site.